# Populate new columns when list values match substring of column values in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `Pyspark` like below

```
df.show()

+---+----------------------+
| id|                   con|
+---+----------------------+
|  3|           mac,mac pro|
|  1|        iphone5,iphone|
|  1| android,android phone|
|  1|    windows,windows pc|
|  1| spy camera,spy camera|
|  2|               camera,|
|  3|             cctv,cctv|
|  2|   apple iphone,iphone|
|  3|           ,spy camera|
+---+----------------------+
```

I want to create new columns based on certain `lists`. Lists are below

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows', 'mac']
```

`Condition:`

```
if a element in a list matches a string/substring in a column then flag the column to the value of that particular list
```

Basically what I want is in `phone_list` I have element `iphone` so that should match `id` `1` where `con` is `iphone5, iphone` and flag as `phones` and so on.

`Expected result`

```
+---+----------------------+------+----+
| id|                   con|   cat| abc|
+---+----------------------+------+----+
|  3|           mac,mac pro|  null|  pc|
|  1|        iphone5,iphone|phones|null|
|  1| android,android phone|phones|null|
|  1|    windows,windows pc|  null|  pc|
|  1| spy camera,spy camera|  null|null|
|  2|               camera,|  null|null|
|  3|             cctv,cctv|  null|null|
|  2|   apple iphone,iphone|phones|null|
|  3|           ,spy camera|  null|null|
+---+----------------------+------+----+
```

I have done like below.

```
df1 = df.withColumn('cat', F.when(df.con.isin(phone_list), 'phones')).withColumn('abc', F.when(df.con.isin(pc_list), 'pc'))
```

`output`

```
df1.show()

+---+----------------------+----+----+
| id|                   con| cat| abc|
+---+----------------------+----+----+
|  3|           mac,mac pro|null|null|
|  1|        iphone5,iphone|null|null|
|  1| android,android phone|null|null|
|  1|    windows,windows pc|null|null|
|  1| spy camera,spy camera|null|null|
|  2|               camera,|null|null|
|  3|             cctv,cctv|null|null|
|  2|   apple iphone,iphone|null|null|
|  3|           ,spy camera|null|null|
+---+----------------------+----+----+
```

How can I do this type of comparison in the correct way?

Comment: Is the `con` column a string, or a list of strings?

Comment: @TravisHegner the `Con` column is a `concatenated` column from two different columns. Basically it is a `string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to avoid using `udf` and use [`pyspark.sql.Column.rlike()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike). This will return `True` if the column matches the regular expression contained within the argument.

In this case, you can use `"|".join(list_of_terms)` to create a regex pattern that will match any word in the list. (`"|"` is the `OR` operator)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.select(
    "*", 
    when(col("con").rlike("|".join(phone_list)), "phones").alias("cat"), 
    when(col("con").rlike("|".join(pc_list)), "pc").alias("abc")
).show(truncate=False)
#+---+---------------------+------+----+
#|id |con                  |cat   |abc |
#+---+---------------------+------+----+
#|3  |mac,mac pro          |null  |pc  |
#|1  |iphone5,iphone       |phones|null|
#|1  |android,android phone|phones|null|
#|1  |windows,windows pc   |null  |pc  |
#|1  |spy camera,spy camera|null  |null|
#|2  |camera,              |null  |null|
#|3  |cctv,cctv            |null  |null|
#|2  |apple iphone,iphone  |phones|null|
#|3  |,spy camera          |null  |null|
#+---+---------------------+------+----+
```

We're also using the fact that [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) will return `null` if no `otherwise()` condition is specified.

Comment: @user9943426 what is `.rlike("|".join(phone_list))` this doing

Comment: @Question_bank `rlike` accepts regular expressions. The `|` is an `OR` operation. So `"|".join(phone_list)` joins the values in `phone_list` with the `|` in between them, and the result is a regular expression pattern that essentially says "if any of the following words match"...

Comment: @user9367133 - I updated this answer to match your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a `udf` function to check for the list of strings to be contained in `con` column should get you the desired output

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows', 'mac']

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def checkIsIn(con):
    phones = None
    pc = None
    for x in phone_list:
        if(x in con):
            phones = 'phones'
    for x in pc_list:
        if x in con:
            pc = 'pc'
    return (phones, pc)

checkIsInUdf = f.udf(checkIsIn, t.StructType([t.StructField('cat', t.StringType(), True), t.StructField('abc', t.StringType(), True)]))

df.withColumn('temp', checkIsInUdf(f.col('con')))\
    .select(f.col('id'), f.col('con'), f.col('temp.*'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---------------------+------+----+
|id |con                  |cat   |abc |
+---+---------------------+------+----+
|3  |mac,mac pro          |null  |pc  |
|1  |iphone5,iphone       |phones|null|
|1  |android,android phone|phones|null|
|1  |windows,windows pc   |null  |pc  |
|1  |spy camera,spy camera|null  |null|
|2  |camera,              |null  |null|
|3  |cctv,cctv            |null  |null|
|2  |apple iphone,iphone  |phones|null|
|3  |,spy camera          |null  |null|
+---+---------------------+------+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: is there a way to do groupBy id and populate count of that column while doing the above itself. For example for `id` `1` `cat column shoul have count 2` and `abc column count 1`

Comment: for that you can just return 1 from udf function if there is match and 0 otherwise and you can sum them in groupBy.